Given a sequence of signed, finite measure. We need to find a finite, positive measure s.t. the sequence is abs. continuous with respect to it.
Question: Let $(X,\mathcal{M})$ be a measure space,  $(\mu_n)$ a sequence of finite, signed measures on $X$. Show that there exists a finite, positive measure $\nu$ on $X$ such $\mu_n$ is absolutely continuous w.r.t. $\nu$ for all $n$.
There is no topology on $X$ which means we don't have access to the dual space $C(X)$. I am not sure what to do here? What we have to work with is that the space of all signed measures on $X$ forms a Banach space under the total variation norm.

Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, etc.; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult this link for further guidance.

Let $|\mu_n|$ be the total variation measure of $\mu_n$. Define
$$ \nu = \sum_n \frac{|\mu_n|}{2^n |\mu_n|(X)} $$
It is easy to prove that $\nu$ is a finite positive measure, such that $\mu_n$ is absolutely continuous w.r.t. $\nu$ for all $n$.

That works, thank you!
